# Jenkins and git

Tags: git, jenkins, console-output

I am using Jenkins for my test system automation. I am using git plugin. All is working well except one thing.

When  I push something in my branch, Jenkins launches my tests etc. But when I click on Console output at the beginning it says "Started by GitHub push by" two times without given to me the guy who pushed (me).

Why "Started by GitHub push by" is present two times?
And how can I just have it one time with the name of the guy who pushed?
 When I click on Changes I can see the commit ID and my username is present.

Comment: You could try disabling the GitHub plugin?

Comment: I tried to disable GitHub plugin and when I pushed that did not launch my build. Then I tried to disable Jenkins git plugin and same thing. I need to have Jenkins git and GitHub plugins activated in order to launch the build when I push something on a git branch...

Answer (score 0):

For using git scm in jenkins you should install 2 pludings.

[Git](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) and [Git client](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Client+Plugin)

Install git client plugin before installing git plugin.

Answer (score -1):

For me, I am using a hook to trigger a build.